# Assistance with: SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a big problem after querying 1 record table, with the following
error information:

> Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Line 1
> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: invalid protection option. It occurred during a read of page (1:40607) in database ID 19 at offset 0x00000013d3e000 in file 'D:\database\20001_30082019.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or operating system error log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid on RESTORE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164417/sql-server-detected-a-logical-consistency-based-i-o-error-incorrect-pageid-on-r)

Answer (score 1):

Error 824 points you to IO subsystem issue. I would highly recommend you to open a support case to Microsoft and they will be able to assist you and pinpoint the root cause. It usually cost you roughly 500USD.

Before you open a case, do due diligence and check your database for corruption. You can find the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-824-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15). The link will give you some guidance on the resolution and possible cause.

From my experience, check your firmware updates and filter drivers (antivirus) as a possible cause this error to show up.

Comment: Thanks for the handling we have finished the whole problem caused by a hardware failure. We've copied all of the hard drive's data to the new hard drive now it's up and running